# VBA Excel SetCurrentDirectory using (ActiveWorkbook.Path) does not work with 64-bit

Tags: excel, vba, 32bit-64bit

We currently made all the changes necessary to get our VBA templates to work with Office 2010 32-bit and 64-bit.  We are running into one issue that I have been trying to resolve.

This is the code that used to work for just 32-bit within the DynamicXLSAppHandler:

```
Dim L_Return As Long

'Set Current Directory in SaveAs dialog
If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> "" Then
    ChDrive (ActiveWorkbook.Path)
    ChDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path)
    L_Return = SetCurrentDirectory(ActiveWorkbook.Path)
End If
```

The purpose of this code is when the user clicks on Save, or Ctrl-S, they are prompted with a SaveAs dialog in the directory (path) that they originally opened the document/template from.  Without this code (because of the 64-bit incompatibility) it now just opens 'Documents' as the default and the users need to browse to the original path.

I am wondering if there is a new way of doing this for 64-bit, or if I have to change things completely.

Comment: Note that `ChDrive` will fail if your workbook happens to be saved on a non-mapped network drive, e.g. if `ActiveWorkbook.Path` is `\\mycompany\somedrive\somefolder`. I just learned this the hard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `SetCurrentDirectory` API in 64-bit, you need to add the [`PtrSafe` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278832.aspx) to the function declaration:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCurrentDirectory Lib "kernel32" _
        Alias "" SetCurrentDirectoryA(ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long 
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectory Lib "kernel32" _
        Alias "" SetCurrentDirectoryA(ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long 
#End If
```

By the way:

- Why do you need `ChDrive` and `ChDir` as well as `SetCurrentDirectory`?
- `ChDrive` should only be passed a drive letter, for example like this:

  `ChDrive Left(ActiveWorkbook.Path, 1)`

Comment: We are not using the API, we have this in an If statement.  We use ChDrive and ChDir to populate the SetCurrentDirectory.  What we do is use that to populate the SendAs pop up so it doesn't throw the person into the default directory (My Documents).

Comment: So what is SetCurrentDirectory in your code? A custom function?

Comment: It is part of a custom Sub Class for steps before Save.  So if I wanted to include the API in this Sub Class, how would I do it using the ActiveWorkbook.Path?

Comment: your code is correct as it is if you have the api declared as I showed. I don't really know what you mean by "Sub Class". If you use the API you don't need ChDrive or ChDir

Comment: One other question, is this code backwards compatible?  So if we use it with Office 32-bit will it work the same or will it throw errors?  Also, I apologize for my incorrect terms, here is the first line of code for the section that holds the first statement:  Private Sub dynamic_Excelapp_workbookBeforeSave(ByVal I_book As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, cancel As Boolean) so where would I put the Private Declare within that?

Comment: I've amended the code for 32bit compatibility. the declaration goes at the top of your class module before any subs

Comment: Thanks Josie, I make a mistake in adding the ChDir and ChDrive, I had forgotten that they were actually commented out ages ago and should now just remove them.  I should be able to get the code updated and tested today, I will update once I test.  Thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: Hi again Josie, it seems the VBA7 does not work correctly.  I get an error when debugging that states "Invalid Outside Procedure".  Note that this is when running in 32 bit Office.

Comment: what's the exact code-that message simply means you have something in the wrong place

Comment: In the end we didn't need the directive of the 'If VBA7, Else'.  I removed that and only coded                                     Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long                                    and that worked.  Thank you for your help.