# change directory - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I am writing something in Excel (VBA) and need to find a certain file to open. I know that it is in a certain directory (folder) but I am having difficulty pointing the Application.GetOpenFilename  to the correct directory/folder (as the default, or starting point).

Is there a command that I can issue to direct the above command to default (start looking) in a specific place?
If it matters, I am using Excel on a PC, Windows 10, Office 2019 and writing VBA

I have searched and keep finding missing pages (error 404) on the internet for VBA. I cant seem to find anything for Directory, Folder, Root.

Is the documentation for VBA all gone?

when I execute the Application.GetOpenFilename, it opens some folder on the computer, but not where I want it to start. How do I direct the command to start by displaying a certain folder?

Ernest

Thank you to the people that posted an answer:
Chdir "C:\user\dump"
before the GetOpenFilname command

Comment: I'm guessing you overlooked `ChDir`.

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68476970/excel-vba-chdir-will-not-change-my-directory) if you need to change drive as well.

Comment: thank you BigBen. Sometimes you just don't know enough to formulate the right question.